# Can we chain multiple API calls or keep track of multiple calls being made at once?

Tags: android, retrofit2, greendao

I have 21 API calls that need to be made once the app gets to the splash screen. What my app does is as follows:
 a> Make API call using retrofit's enqueue method.
 b> once the response is available(call success) it stores data to local database using greendao. Inside app it only uses data from greendao databases. What I need is to keep track of the api call whether it failed or not. If failed retry. Also if there is a way to chain the requests can anyone mention them? I looked into rxjava which allows chaining upto 2 or 3 apis (as far as I know). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create IntentService which will run `call.execute()` code one by one.

This way you will call synchronous call to all apis.

Once all request completes send broadcast to activity or communicate with activity through other mechanism.